# Implementing wcf with mvc4 entity framework fails invoking method

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I have a wcf  application in which i have used Entitity Framework and have implemented dbContext for querying the database.
When I view the svc file in browser it exposes the operations.

I have interface class like this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
       List<BooksModels> GetBooksList();

        [OperationContract]
        BooksModels GetBook(int id);

    }
```

I have the implementation in the svc.cs file like this

```
    public List<BooksModels> GetBooksList()
    {
        MVCEntity en = new MVCEntity();
      return  en.book.ToList();

    }

    public int GetBookId(int id)
    {
        //return db.book.Find(id);
        return 1;
    }
```

and the BooksModels class is like this

```
[DataContract]
    public class BooksModels
        {
            [Key]
            [DataMember]
            public int BookId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
    public string BookName{get;set;}
    }
```

and have the config file the default one as created when creating wcf service application .

but when i invoke GetBooksList the service from MVC wcf client  it gives me the following error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

but when i invoke the second method that returns 1.

i examined that when the service uses the dbContext to return data it gives error and 
is fine when not.

I have gone through various blogs and also the questions in stackoverflow but didn't help. 
so how can this problem be addressed.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to debug your `GetBooksList()` method?

Comment: Have you tried communicating with your WCF service directly using the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes the method works fine if it is in the controller not invoked as service .

Comment: @Veleous yes i have Tested it with WCF Test Client  and the test is fine with second method but yeilds errror for the first one.

Comment: @ElAmorZeewon - How have you implemented your service proxy, could you provide some code?

Comment: @Veleous it only has the default config file  provided when creating the wcf application service . service works fine when data is not returning using dbContext.

Comment: @ElAmorZeewon - I assume that your `dbContext` is querying your database, then using the results to generate instances of `BookModels`?  If so, have you correctly defined a `WCF DataContract` for these objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of serialization. Make a serialisation test from you're business layer that take List from entity framework and serialize then deserialize it and compare before and after serialization.

Use DataContractSerializer :

```
DataContractSerializer serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<BooksModels>));
List<BooksModels> expected = business.GetBooksList();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
serialiser.WriteObject(stream, expected);
stream.Position = 0;
List<BooksModels> actual = serialiser.ReadObject(stream) as List<BooksModels>;
Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Prop1, actual.Prop1);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Prop2, actual.Prop2);
// ... //
```

If it doesn't work you probably use proxy in entity framework. turn off proxy :

```
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Have you got an exception when you test the serialization with DataContractSerializer ? It's important to know if the problem is a serialization issue.

Comment: You could activate WCF Tracing too like it's explain in MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Thanks to Brice2Paris, I solved it by turning off the proxy of EF:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```